# REGEX - Get specific values

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript and I want the user to enter only one of below 4 values.

PL, PH, M, MH

How can I use REGEX to test it?

Comment: Why would you use a regexp for this? Just put them in an array and use `valid_inputs.includes(input)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an exercise in using Regular Expressions, so you really want to use a Regular Expression to solve it, you can do something like this:

```js
regex = /^(PL|PH|MH|M)$/

choices = ["PL", "PH", "M", "MH", "other", "invalid", "value"]
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)
input = choices[index]
console.log("Testing", '"'+input+'"')

x = input.match(regex) 
if (x) {
  x = x[0]
}

console.log("Output:", x) // << one of the allowed strings, or null
```

Press [ (>) Run code snippet ] multiple times to see different output values.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not appropriate for such simple task. Better would be to define array with values, and check if entered value is in that array, i.e.:

```
let allowedValues = ['PL', 'PH', 'M', 'MH'];
let isInputCorrect = allowedValues.includes(inputtedValue);
```

Nevertheless, regex for that would be: `(?:PL|PH|M|MH)`

Explanation:

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`PL|PH|M|MH` - alternation - match one of listed values.

Comment: Thanks but 'MH' doesn't seem to be caught